# Как реализовать данную кнопку?

Tags: html, css

без картинок
а только на чистом css

речь о декоре справа
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: шрифтом типа font-awesome, либо html сущностью `&#129133`;

Comment: @highpassion  ради одной картинки шрифт?

Comment: откуда мне знать, сколько их у вас. используйте html entity, что я скинул

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Вариант](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1319626/221218) с градиентом от **UModeL** считаю лучший, но подкину вариант на блоках, ы.

```css
.arrow {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #f34841;
  position: relative;
  pointer-events: none;
  --ac: #fff; /* arrow color */
}

.arrow > span {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
}

.arrow::before,
.arrow::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  right: 5%;
}

.arrow::before {
  width: 70%;
  height: 10%;
  border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
}

.arrow::after {
  width: 10%;
  height: 70%;
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
}

.arrow > span,
.arrow::before,
.arrow::after {
  background: var(--ac);
  pointer-events: all;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.arrow:hover {
  --ac: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow">
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Даже есть своя таргет-зона у стрелки.

Answer (score 3):

Как вариант, так. Находите спецсимволы стрелок, к примеру тут: https://unicode-table.com/ru/sets/arrow-symbols/#diagonal-arrows

Выбираете нужную вам стрелку, узнаёте её юникод или, что ещё лучше, код стрелки для css. Остальное - совсем просто. Кнопку я реализовал тегом `a`, изначально он строчный, я делаю его блочным ради отступов и возможности задавать ширину, а стрелку задаю псевдоэлементом `after`. Код примерный, окончательное оформление: цвета, шрифт и его размеры укажите сами.

```css
.button {
  display: block;
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: #f34841;
  width: 300px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'verdana', sans serif;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
}
 
.button:after {
  content: "\1F865";
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="button">Отправить</a>
```

Comment: Какой красивый квадратик вместо стрелки ;-)

Comment: @UModeL Упс, у меня в опере,и ff отображается стрелка.

Comment: везёт Вам :)) Я с Хрома сижу...

Comment: @UModeL, открыл в хроме, и тут у меня всё отображается. Но ваш вариант прекрасен и кроссбраузерный.

Comment: в FF тоже квадратик, но уже с кодом символа :) Я специально не обновляю шрифты в системе (Win7), чтобы тестить подобные случаи. И, думаю, ещё очень много простых пользователей даже не в курсе подобных нюансов. При этом я и остальные пользуемся последними версиями браузеров.

Comment: @UModeL Теперь понимаю. Установлена Win10, специально шрифты не обновлял, но, очевидно, всё уже и так установлено, стало быть просто не мог бы воссоздать у себя данную ошибку. Но я уже и так сказал, что ваш вариант прекрасен и стоит выбрать именно его.

Answer (score 0):

Как я понял тут 2 spanа. В первом надпись отправить и в втором стрелка ➚(`&#129133`). И в стилях у второго `display : inline-block;`. И у самой кнопки есть паддинги.

Comment: это да, так суть только в стрелке

Comment: сделать без картинок. на чистом css